# Eclipse PDT 2.2.0 does not track Symfony classes

Tags: eclipse, symfony1, eclipse-pdt

My last version of Eclipse PDT does not track symfony project code and so i cannot use autocomplete and search class actions.

I have last version symfony 1.4  included in my project's /lib dir.
(I'am teaching symfony now with a Jobeet reference project to be concrete).

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Just deleted project, manualy deleted .buildpath file in the project's root and recreated project.

I tryied without any effect before:

- refresh workspace
- delete and recreate all the project (without deleting the source codes)

nothing helped me...

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your project is set as PHP project?

Right click on the project and select Configure | Add PHP nature..

Comment: Oh yeah, it is, every other my PHP projects are succesfully tracked in the same Eclipse PDT.
I think the reason is that Symfony contains some PHP invalid files which brakes code tracking..